# Equivalence in CLT proof

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm studying the proof of CLT in [this](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Krokhmal.pdf) pdf. My issue is at pag 11.

Let's consider the Moment Generating Function $M(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})$.
The author applies the logarithm to this function getting $nln(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})$.

I'm not able to understand how he came to this result. $M(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})$ is defined as $E[e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}}]$, i don't know how to handle this expected value...

Comment: There is no $\ln(t/\sqrt{n})$ on p.11. there is $L(t/\sqrt{n})$, and $L$ is defined at the end of p.10 as $L(u) = \ln M(u)$.

Comment: Thanks. If you write it as an aswer i vote you

Comment: PS: why de l'hopital is applicable also for $x\rightarrow +\infty $ ? Its definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_form)  doesn't mention it...

Comment: It does: "Let $c$ and $L$ be extended real numbers (i.e., real numbers, positive infinity, or negative infinity)."

Comment: Seems all should be clear now from discussion with @ClementC. If still unclear start at top of p10 where the MGF of $\sum_i X_i/\sqrt{n}$ is found in (1)-(4). Then from (1) and (2) at the bottom of p10 on to (3)-(5) on p11, where each step is explained below (5).

Comment: @Qwerto Done. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there is **no** expression involving $n\ln\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}$ in the linked lecture notes. There is, however, the expression
$$
nL\!\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$
on p.11, which is not the same; and indeed, there is nothing abnormal there, as the function $L$ is defined at the bottom of p.10 bt
$$
L(u) = \ln M(u)\,.
$$
Therefore, indeed
$$
\ln \left(M\!\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n\right) = nL\!\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$
by very definition.